# Syntax errors on VS Code with Vue3 + TypeScript + Vite

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vuejs3, yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2

I'm setting up a new project using Vite, Vue 3 and Typescript. To do so, I'm using yarn

```sh
yarn create vite
```

I then get prompted for the project name (vite-project), then the framework (vue) and then the variant (vue-ts).

```
✔ Project name: … vite-project
✔ Select a framework: › vue
✔ Select a variant: › vue-ts
```

After the project is scaffolded, because I want to use yarn PnP, I set it up for the latest version. *And there's a clue here, because if I don't do this and use the classic version of yarn, I don't get the syntax errors.*

```sh
cd vite-project
yarn set version berry
```

I then test the project

```sh
yarn
yarn dev
```

All works as expected.

Now comes the issue. I open up the project with VS Code

```sh
code .
```

I then install the recommended extensions

- vue.volar
- Vue.vscode-typescript-vue-plugin

I instantly get an issue when opening up `App.vue` file.

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
Cannot find module 'vue' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

As I said before, if I don't use the PnP version of yarn, I don't get these errors.

Does anyone have any idea of how to fix this, or should I stick to classic `yarn` or `npm` instead?

Comment: Try remove and install the `node_modules` again

Answer (score 1):

Install [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Vue.vscode-typescript-vue-plugin) Volar plugin for typescript with vue.

Comment: It works for my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it with:

```
npm install
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).